# What does go install do?

Tags: go

The docs say nothing about what `build` vs `install` does

My expectation was that it's like `make install`; i.e. it takes the compiled stuff and puts in its final location (`/usr/local/bin/my_new_toy` or whatever) but it seems that it puts things in `GOROOT/bin`

Can I tell go to do a `make install` - i.e. put things elsewhere? Or do I just write a makefile (please tell me no)?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you want binary files to go to a specific location, you can use the environment variable `GOBIN` :

> The bin/ directory holds compiled commands. Each command is named for
>   its source directory, but only the final element, not the entire path.
>   That is, the command with source in DIR/src/foo/quux is installed into
>   DIR/bin/quux, not DIR/bin/foo/quux. The foo/ is stripped so that you
>   can add DIR/bin to your PATH to get at the installed commands. **If the
>   GOBIN environment variable is set, commands are installed to the
>   directory it names instead of DIR/bin.**

Source : http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable

```
GOBIN=/usr/local/bin/ go install
```

If you want per-project `bin/` directory then you can simply append your project path to `GOPATH`, however you must have your code under `$project-path/src/` and `go install` will put all the binaries in `$project-path/bin`.

```
export GOPATH=/dir1:/dir2:/dir3
```

> If GOBIN is not set, binaries from /dir1/src end up in /dir1/bin,
>   binaries from /dir2/src end up in /dir2/bin, and so on (and binaries
>   from $GOROOT/src end up in $GOROOT/bin).

Source : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/-mN8R_Fx-7M

And you can also just use (thanks JimB):

```
go build -o /path/binary-name
```

Comment: you can also specify the output filename directly with `go build -o`

Comment: Yep that too, gonna add that to the answer for completeness sake.

Comment: so go install is the same as go build -o $GOPATH/bin/<package>?

Comment: More or less, it also installed library files (`blah.a`) to `$GOPATH/pkg/`.

Comment: `go env` will show the assumed `GOPATH` and all other variables

Comment: as far as I know go build can handle "main" packages only

Comment: If instaling Go via asdf, you need to run `asdf reshim golang` so the installed binaries are made available. `go env`  will indicate where those binaries actually live (check GOBIN and GOPATH variables)

Answer (score 122):

## `go build` vs `go install:`

> `go build` just compiles the executable file and moves it to the destination.
> `go install` does a little bit more. It moves the executable file to
> `$GOPATH/bin` and caches all non-main packages which are imported to
> `$GOPATH/pkg`. The cache will be used during the next compilation provided the
> source did not change yet.

---

### A package tree after `go build` and `go install`:

```sh
.
├── bin
│   └── hello  # by go install
└── src 
    └── hello
        ├── hello  # by go build
        └── hello.go
```

---

[More detailed information](https://github.com/NanXiao/golang-101-hacks/blob/master/posts/go-build-vs-go-install.md).

Comment: Does `go install` also builds? Or do I need to run `go build` before installing?

Comment: @RafaelEyng No, `go install` is enough, but its exec file creates in `bin/` directory

Comment: I have a project where I type 'go install' and nothing happens. No error message, just nothing. What's going on?

Comment: Whats the usecase for `go install`? As I understand the result of `go build` can be distributed and run on different machines whereas `go install` needs the sourcecode and installs the go program locally.

Comment: @fabs The usecase is that you have written a tool in Go that you want to use yourself. You want to just be able to do `mytool foo` at the terminal, so you add `$GOPATH/bin` to your terminal's `PATH` and then `go install` makes the magic happen.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek thanks for this, so you would not use `go install` in a build pipeline for example, only `go build`.

Comment: My experience on Linux (Mint/Ubuntu) is that it goes to ~/go/bin without any $GO* variables

Comment: `go env` helps debugging: I forgot that I was using Asdf, which needs a "reshim" call after binary installs. @user2023370: it logs nothing if the package is already installed. The first install call should show some downloads.

Comment: Clean explanation. TY