# What does go build build? (go build vs. go install)

Tags: go, build, compilation

New Go programmers often don't know or get confused what the fundamental go build command does.

What do exactly the `go build` and `go install` commands build and where do they put the result/output?

Comment: [go build vs go install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54429573/3702377)

Answer (score 201, accepted):

What the `go` command does depends on whether we run it for a "normal" package or for the special `"main"` package.

**For packages**

- `go build`   builds your package then *discards the results*.
- `go install` builds then *installs* the package in your `$GOPATH/pkg` directory.

**For commands (package `main`)**

- `go build`   builds the command and leaves the result in the *current working directory*.
- `go install` builds the command in a temporary directory then moves it to `$GOPATH/bin`.

#### What to pass to `go build`?

You may pass *packages* to `go build`, packages you want to build. You may also pass a list of `.go` files from a single directory, which is then treated as the list of source files specifying a single package.

If no packages (import paths) are provided, the build is applied on the current directory.

An import path may contain one or more `"..."` wildcards (in which case it is a *pattern*).  `...` can match any string, e.g. `net/...` matches the `net` package and packages being in any of its subfolders. The command

```
go build ./...
```

often used to build the package in the current folder and all packages recursing down. This command issued in a project root builds the complete project.

For more about specifying packages, run `go help packages`.

#### Regarding modules

Preliminary support for Go modules was introduced in Go 1.11, and modules became default starting with Go 1.13. When the `go` tool is run from a folder which contains a `go.mod` file (or one of the parents of the current folder), the `go` tool runs in *module-aware* mode (the legacy mode is called *GOPATH mode*).

> In module-aware mode, GOPATH no longer defines the meaning of imports
>   during a build, but it still stores downloaded dependencies (in GOPATH/pkg/mod)
>   and installed commands (in GOPATH/bin, unless GOBIN is set).

When building modules, what is built is specified by the *build list*. The build list initially contains only the main module (the module containing the directory where the `go` command is run), and the dependencies of the main module are added to the build list, recursively (dependencies of dependencies are also added).

For more info, run `go help modules`.

---

Basically you can use `go build` as a check that the packages can be built (along with their dependencies) while `go install` also (permanently) installs the results in the proper folders of your `$GOPATH`.

`go build` will silently terminate if everything is OK, and will give you error messages if the packages cannot be built/compiled.

Whenever the `go` tool installs a package or binary, it also installs whatever dependencies it has, so running `go install` will also install packages your program depends on (publicly available, "go gettable" packages), automatically.

For a start, read the official [**How to Write Go Code**](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) page.

More information about the `go` tool: [**Command go**](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)

You can also get more help by running the following command:

```
go help build
```

It is also worth noting that starting with Go 1.5 `go install` also removes executables created by `go build` ([source](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/10682/)):

> If 'go install' (with no arguments, meaning the current directory)
>   succeeds, remove the executable written by 'go build', if present. This avoids leaving a stale binary behind...

To complete the list, `go run` compiles your application into a temporary folder, and starts that executable binary. When the app exits, it properly cleans up the temporary files.

<sub>Question inspired by Dave Cheney's [What does go build build?](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/06/04/what-does-go-build-build)</sub>

Comment: seems strange that go install does not update the executable if its identical to previously installed one ... any insights here ?

Comment: i still dont get how i can run the binary that `go build ./...` makes

Comment: @AthulMuralidhar Are you asking how to find or how to start the result executable binary or binaries?

Comment: yep, so ideally with the `-o` flag we would be able to make our own name for the binary build - but with the `./...` its not possible right? and i did check with the `-x` flag, seems like the binary is built in `/tmp` - i would like to give it a custom name and build it in the dir where i run the `./...` cmd - idk how to :/

Comment: `go build ./...` will not leave executable binaries.

Comment: is there any other workaround for this? - well anyways thx for the replies :)

Comment: Workaround for what? Supply the package path of the `main` package if you want to have a binary in the end.

Answer (score 20):

For package:

> `go build`: builds your package then *discards* the results

That won't be true after Go 1.10 (Q1 2018), thank to  [CL 68116](https://golang.org/cl/68116) and [CL 75473](https://golang.org/cl/75473). See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/qfa3mHN4ZPA/X2UzjNV1BAAJ), that I reference here.

> > What do exactly the `go build` and `go install` commands build
>
> Whenever the go tool installs a package or binary, it also installs whatever dependencies it has, so running go install will also install packages your program depends on (publicly available, "go gettable" packages), automatically.

Actually... `go install` will change also with Go 1.10, *in addition* of the new cache:

> The "`go install`" command **no longer installs dependencies of the named packages** ([CL 75850](https://golang.org/cl/75850)).
>
> **If you run "`go install foo`", the only thing installed is `foo`**.
>
> Before, it varied. If dependencies were out-of-date, "`go install`" also installed any dependencies.
>   The implicit installation of dependencies during "`go install`" caused a lot of confusion and headaches for users, but it was previously necessary to enable incremental builds.
>   Not anymore.
>   We think that the new "`install what I said`" semantics will be much more understandable, especially since it's clear from bug reports that many users already expected them.
>   **To force installation of dependencies during "`go install`", use the new "`go install -i`"**, by analogy with "`go build -i`" and "`go test -i`".
>
> The fact that "`go install`" used to install any rebuilt dependencies caused confusion most often in conjunction with `-a`, which means "`force rebuild of all dependencies`".
>   Now, "`go install -a myprog`" will force a complete rebuild of all dependencies of `myprog`, as well as `myprog` itself, but only `myprog` will get installed. (All the rebuilt dependencies will still be saved in the build cache, of course.)
>   Making this case work more understandably is especially important in conjunction with the new content-based staleness analysis, because it sees good reasons to rebuild dependencies more often than before, which would have increased the amount of "why did my dependencies get installed" confusion.
>   For example, if you run "`go install -gcflags=-N myprog`", that installs a `myprog` built with no compiler optimizations, but it no longer also reinstalls the packages `myprog` uses from the standard library without compiler optimizations.

Comment: Does `go build`, do `get`s? I have a build error `cannot find package "github.com/spf13/cobra" in any of:…`. I don't know how to tell it to get it. Do I need to explicitly get?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor With which version of Go? Does your project has a `go.mod` file in it?

Comment: `go version go1.11.4 linux/amd64`. I don't know about go.mod. I am re-building `https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache/blob/master/cmd/mustache/main.go`, it is odd as I just built the whole package, and am using this example as a base, and I did create a more basic version that worked (but not using this library). I can't see how it was not installed with the mustache package.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor so cobr is vendored https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache/tree/master/cmd/mustache/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra. Is your GOPATH properly set?

Comment: I have discovered what you already found. The package is in a vendor sub-directory: this is why it did not get installed. However I don't know why it does not install it now on build. Or how to use the vendor directory (if I copy it to my directory).