# How do I turn my Go code into a library?

Tags: go, libraries

I know how to make a function that adds up all the parameters given to it and one for subtraction and I wanted to make a simple math library for adding and subtracting and multiplying and dividing, but my internet searches for how to compile into a library came up with no results. I would like to know if there is a way to make a .go into a library and if so how do you do it. I am still very new to Go. If you know how to please tell me

Comment: Read [this](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), [this](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/12/01/five-suggestions-for-setting-up-a-go-project) and [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GithubCodeLayout) for a start. Oh, and [this](https://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code), too.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `go install` on your package, it will create a static library with the name of that package for you, and place it in your `GOPATH/pkg/ARCH/packageName/packageName.a`. For example, if you have your `$GOPATH` set as `/home/yourname/go`, you can create the following file:

`/home/yourname/go/src/myMath/myMath.go`

with the content of:

```
package myMath

func MyAdd(/* .... */) { // Capatalize the name of the function to allow it to be accessible from outside of this package
   // Do stuff
}
```

Now, if you do a `go install`, you will have a `myMath.a` library in the directory above.

To use this library from another go package, `myStats` say, you can do the following:

```
package myStats

import "myMath" // import your library. notice the "" around the name

func someFunction(/* .... */) {
   r := myMath.MyAdd(/* ..... */)
}
```

Notice again that you have to capitalized the name of the functions you wish to be used from outside of your package. For example, if your add function was called `myAdd`, then it would not been accessible from `myStats` even if you do import the `myMath` package.

**Edit** fixed some errors based on the comments from @icza, below.

Comment: Package folder is `pkg` (not `pack`), and `go build` does not create a `*.a` file (it discards the result). See [What does go build build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build)