# Go build with built-in dependencies

Tags: http, go, server, dependencies

I'm very new to system programming.

I have a Go program which uses `net/http` and starts an http server.

When I build a Windows binary and tried on a target Windows machine, nothing worked except `Printf`s before it starts the server.

As soon as I installed Go on the target Windows machine, everything started working!

Here is my program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there @%s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {

    path, err := exec.LookPath("go")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Go is not your fortune :|")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Go is available at %s\n", path)

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

If `go` doesn't build all the dependencies with its program then how do I do it? If it does, why it is not working?

Does target systems have to have `go` installed prior to run any Go programs?

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it crashed on loading dynamic libraries. Perhaps after you've installed `go` the necessary binaries ended up in win32/wow64 directory, hence it worked? You could try adding the necessary runtime dynamic libraries to the binary directory (or PATH) and see if that's enough.

Comment: The runtime does not require the source to be installed. You need to show how you build the binary and what output you received.

Comment: @JimB I've added my program. In case `Go` is not installed, it just logs the err and exits!

Comment: Your program is looking for the `go` binary, so of course Go needs to be installed. Why are you doing `exec.LookPath("go")`?

Comment: @JimB I need checking on whether some commands exists on target system, so that was my test! Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: change log.Fatal() to log.Printf(), and it should work (and you probably don't need to `exec.LookPath("go")` since Go does not have to be installed on the target machine)

Comment: @dmitris Yes! My program will require some commands to be run on target machine so `exec.LookPath("go")` was just a test to check if it works. I'll probably also require `log.Fatal()` as well because without some commands on target machine(not `go`), my program will not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app doesn't work without Go because you call [`log.Fatal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal) if it doesn't find the `go` tool, and `log.Fatal()` *terminates* your app:

> Fatal is equivalent to Print() **followed by a call to os.Exit(1)**.

Your executable binary will contain everything it needs if you build it from the source you posted either with `go build` or `go install` (see [What does go build build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build) for details). Just don't call `log.Fatal()` and it should work.

And on a side note: you *should* check and print errors returned by [`http.ListenAndServe()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe), e.g.:

```
panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

Because if this fails, you won't know why it doesn't work (e.g. you already started the app and the port is taken / in use).

Comment: Well noted! Thank so much for help!

Answer (score 2):

No, the target system does not have to have the Go compiler installed for the executable compiled with Go to run. You can compile your program with `go install` or `go build` on one Windows computer, copy it to another one where Go is **not** installed and run it there.

Make sure the program that you compile starts with the `package main` statement - otherwise only a library file will be compiled.

Make sure to check whether the user that runs your program has rights to listen on the port that the http server uses.  The ports 0-1023 - "Well Known Ports" - "can only be used by system (or root) processes or by programs executed by privileged users" (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/174904), so try to start your program as a privileged user (for example, Administrator) or use a non-privileged port >= 1024 (ex. `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)` should start the server on a non-privilege port.  Take a very simple example - for example from https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/ - and see if you can get it to work.