# go install fails if I am outside of the .go file directory

Tags: go

I installed Golang via the suggestion https://golang.org/doc/install and it seems I cannot run the `go install` command like they do on the website

If I run the command from any directory besides the directory that is home to the `.go` file, then it gives me this error. for example:

```
go install ./src/tutorial/helloworld/hello.go
```

or

```
go install ./path/to/.go/file/hello.go

go install: no install location for .go files listed on command line (GOBIN not set)
```

but if I run the install from inside the directory that has the `.go` file everything goes well and it places the final executable in the `GOPATH` `bin` folder.

```
//In the folder that contains my .go file
go install
```

I have set `GOPATH` in my `.bash_profile` and the go installation added the go root directory in `/usr/local/go/bin` to my `PATH`

Any ideas why I cannot run install from outside the directory like the instructions on the golang.org website says?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the exact command that you are running.

Comment: I have added the commands

Comment: @deltaskelta: Also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to the `go install` command are packages, not .go files. Use these commands to specify the package by relative path.

For the package containing the file ./src/tutorial/helloworld/hello.go:

```
go install ./src/tutorial/helloworld
```

For the package containing the file ./path/to/.go/file/hello.go:

```
go install ./path/to/.go/file
```

Comment: I see. I totally misread the helloworld program install instructions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the chosen answer solution, but didn't work for me, given me the following error

> cannot find main module, but found .git/config in 'path/to/root/of/project'
> to create a module there, run:
> cd .. && go mod init

When i searched for a bit, I found out that I need to git init in the folder where the mod exists, I don't know if I understood the solution, but I didn't want to add a git init as I have one in the root folder

Context " I want to run go install in `root-folder/dir1/` "

I found using `go help build`

> -C dir
> Change to dir before running the command.
> Any files named on the command line are interpreted after
> changing directories.
> So what worked for me is

```
go install -C  ./path/to/.go/file
```