# command not found after go build

Tags: go

I have install and setup go.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

I have created a [package](https://github.com/shamsher31/gosymbol) at following location.

```
$HOME/go/src/github.com/shamsher31/gosymbol
```

I build inside package folder using

```
go build
```

It creates binary in `bin` folder inside `GOPATH`
But when I try to run package name from command line it gives following error.

```
symbol: command not found
```

How can I execute binary from command line ?

Comment: Have you added `$GOPATH/bin` to your PATH?

Comment: And use `go install` to install the binary in GOPATH/bin

Comment: Yes I already did both the steps you mentioned

Comment: Related: [What does go build build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build) `go build` leaves the executable in the current working directory.

Comment: And btw your package name is `gosymbol`, not `symbol`.

Comment: @icza please have a look at https://github.com/shamsher31/gosymbol/blob/master/symbol.go#L2 name . there is no restriction that folder and package name should be same.

Comment: That isn't a `main` package. It doesn't build a binary.

Answer (score 36):

You need following configuration for ubuntu.

```
$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following config

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/go;
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin;
```

`/usr/local/go/bin` will be your go installation path and 
`$GOPATH/bin` will be where your custom build packages will get installed.

Comment: Also don't forget to reload the configuration once its changed with `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks, this work for me. I using zshrc, sudo nano ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem on OSX, I found this the easiest way to get golang up and running:

With HomeBrew:

```
brew install go
```

Then add these to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/.go
```

Answer (score 2):

i was the same problem in mac but i'm using zsh

I was able to solve the problem by editing the file ~/.zsh

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/go;
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin;
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Go** latest version **go1.13.7 and above**

If you have installed Go in its default location, then you no need to set up the `GOROOT` path.

The default location for **Unix** or **macOS** is `/usr/local/go` and for **Windows**  - `c:\Go`.

You can verify the path using the command `go env`.

**Note:** If you are the getting the same error "command not found", then you need to unset [`GOROOT`](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really).

If you want to set up Go in the preferred location, then you need to export the `GOROOT` path like this:

```sh
export GOROOT="/your/preferred/location"
```

and

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:$GOROOT/bin"
```

in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

1. Set `$GOPATH` env, e.g., `$HOME/go`
2. Add `$GOPATH/bin` into `$PATH`

It should work now.

Comment: on windows its %GOPATH% into %PATH%

Comment: Pretty sure that should be %GOPATH%\bin added to %PATH% if you are on WIndows

Answer (score 0):

for mac

example I put custom go folder in workspace directory. you could change my custom go directory `workspace` by your own.

add the following script to .bashrc

```
export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
export GOPATH="$HOME/workspace/go"
export PATH="$HOME/workspace/go/bin:$PATH"
```

then run `source .bashrc` on your terminal

Answer (score 0):

as  **icza** said

> go build leaves the executable in the current working directory.

Maybe help add ./ to you run command.

```
go build
./symbol
```