# Incorrect package name not throwing error on build

Tags: go

Considering the sample hello world with the wrong package name with the file named as `main.go`

```
package test

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

on `go build main.go` the build doesn't work (doesn't generate the executable) because of the incorrect package name. But why no error is thrown?

Comment: What error would you expect? There's nothing invalid there.

Comment: If it is not generating build file means is it failing? I'm new to go actually.

Comment: It's compiling the package, just not to an executable (since the package isn't called 'main'). That's what it should do.

Answer (score 3):

A package name `test` is not incorrect, it is valid according to [Spec: Package clause:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_clause)

```
PackageClause  = "package" PackageName .
PackageName    = identifier .
```

`test` is a valid Go identifier.

As to what does `go build main.go` do?

Generally you list packages to `go build`, but you may also list `.go` source files, just as in your example.

Quoting from `go help build`:

> If the arguments to build are a list of .go files, build treats them as a list of source files specifying a single package.

So `go build` simply built your `test` package, consisting of a single `main.go` source file. It is not an error to add a `main()` function to a package that is not `main`.

As to why "nothing" happens: `go build` generates no output if everything is ok, and it outputs error if something is not right. `go build` applied on a non-`main` package just "checks" if the package can be built, but it discards the result. Please check [What does go build build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build/30612612#30612612)

Comment: I meant it failed to generate the build file. Not a syntax error in the code. I will go through the link.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC `go build` shouldn't generate anything for non-main packages. So it works as expected.