# go build in docker: unexpected binary in /go/bin

Tags: docker, go

According to this post: [What does go build build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build)

`go build` builds the binary and leaves it in the current directory, while `go install` moves the binary into `$GOPATH/bin`.

This works on my machine like that. However, I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest
ADD . /go/src/myapp
WORKDIR /go/src/myapp
RUN go get .
RUN go build 
RUN ls /go/bin # shows myapp!!
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/myapp"] #works!!
```

There should be no difference here. The expected result was that `/go/bin` was empty and the binary `myapp` would be  `/go/src/myapp/myapp`
Instead, I see that build is working like install, and the binary shows up in /go/bin. Why??

Comment: The `go get` command may do that. What happens if you remove the build command? Is /go/bin/myapp still there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `go get` command is installing your package into /go/bin. If you dont want to install your current package then pass `-d` to stop after downloading your dependencies.

> The -d flag instructs get to stop after downloading the packages; that is, it instructs get not to install the packages.

https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

Comment: why is the behavior different on my local machine? Also, is go build overwriting it?

Comment: I have confirmed that in Docker, passing -d breaks the dockerfile as expected, so this answer is correct. However it is still a mystery why go get doesn't function the same locally. Doing an ls on bin after go get locally does NOT find myapp.

Comment: @Tommy do you have your software on the GOPATH on your local machine? Go tools have different behaviour depending on the GOPATH. I did my test on both local and docker and go get installed the binary on GOPATH/bin.