# How to clear the execution cache in go

Tags: go

When I use flag package

```
// main.go

import (
  ...
  "flag"  
)

func main() {
  ...
  flag.Parse()

  switch flag.Arg(0) {
  case "doSomething1":
    ...
  case "doSomething2":
    ...
  }

}
```

If doSomething1 argument print some error message for me, whatever I fix the source code, it can not remove the old error code and compile again.

```
// command-line

# go build ./main.go
# ./main doSomething1
# error doSomething1 can not work

-- I fix my code

# ./main doSomething1
# error doSomething1 can not work

-- the error message also show me again
-- I have to delete main and build again

# rm ./main
# go build ./main.go
# ./main.go doSomething1
# doSomething1 now can work
```

Comment: If you don't rebuild, you're calling the binary built with the old code. Changing source has no impact on the binary until you rebuild it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go is a [compiled language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language). When you run `go build`, it will compile your sources and create an executable binary. This is what you run when executing `./main doSomething1`.

When you change your sources and run `./main doSomething1`, you are not compiling again, you just run the previously built (and unchanged) binary.

To quickly test changes, use `go run` instead:

```
go run main.go doSomething1
```

That will always compile your sources, build a binary in a temporary folder, launch it and clear it once your app exits.

For details, see [What does go build build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build)