# Go build does not generate binary file from grumpy generated go code?

Tags: python, go, build, binaryfiles, grumpy

I wrote a `HelloWorld.py` and using [grumpy](https://github.com/google/grumpy), I compiled the `HelloWorld.py` to a Go source code.

The `go build` is executed  successfully without any errors but there was no binary file found in the folder.

I need to know where I can found the binary file of my code.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build-go-build-vs-go-install).

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your directory setup.  I think the simple answer is just to use the -o option to write it in your current directory.

```
go build -o mybin
```