# Building a Go project: go mod download vs go build

Tags: go, build, circleci, go-modules

I'm new to go and am trying to figure out how to execute the build step in my circleci project.

I noticed in the CircleCI [Go orb](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/go), that there was no use of `go build`, which was confusing to me because in the CircleCI [Go Language Guide](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-go/), they specifically use `go build` via a [makefile](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-go/blob/master/Makefile).

So I am not sure if using the Go orb alone is sufficient (though that seems odd to me). I vaguely understand what [go mod download](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-download) does, and what [go build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build-go-build-vs-go-install) does, but I've seen [examples](https://medium.com/@pliutau/docker-and-go-modules-4265894f9fc) where they are used together:

```
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

Currently, according to the go orb usage doc, I have:

```
  build:
    executor: go
    steps:
      - checkout
      - go/load-cache:
          key: go-mod-v1-{{ checksum "go.sum" }}
      - go/mod-download
      - go/save-cache:
          key: go-mod-v1-{{ checksum "go.sum" }}
      - slack/notify:
          event: fail
          template: basic_fail_1
```

What am I missing or unintentionally including by using `go mod download` instead of `go build` or `go build` with `go mod download`?

Comment: Did you test it? How was the output not conforming to your expectations?

Comment: Doing a `go mod download` in a build CI/CD setting has the advantage that if `go mod download` fails you have an individual step that fails and it is clear(er) that your build pipeline has a problem _finding_ or _accessing_ a dependency and not in compiling your code (or that of a dependency). This can help identifying problems (e.g. with private repos) faster.

Answer (score 2):

`go mod download` downloads source code for all dependency modules, and verifies checksums for newly-downloaded modules. (Note that in Go 1.18 we [plan to change](https://golang.org/issue/44435) the behavior of `go mod download` so that it can instead download only the modules needed to build packages and tests in in main module.)

`go build` builds packages. It automatically downloads (and verifies) module source code as needed to build those packages. In many cases, that is a much smaller set of modules than what is downloaded by `go mod download`.

Comment: I am not sure why CircleCI would use `go mod download` instead of `go build`. The `go` command has a separate cache for built object files, so if the goal is to speed up builds then it seems like you would get a strictly larger speedup by running an initial `go build` and then saving the resulting contents of *both* the module cache and the build cache.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of [go mod download](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-download) details that all dependencies will be downloaded as no argument is provided.

> With no arguments, download applies to all dependencies of the main
> module.

The lines in the question seem to be a subset of the complete instructions of the CI job. The example from [Circle CI documentation](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/go) suggests a build step which is mandatory to get an executable.

Any [build](https://golang.org/ref/mod#build-commands) command allows to choose the behavior regarding dependencies. As suggested, having a separate `go mod download` depends on the constraints of the environment.