# Change go path explicitly on docker image

Tags: docker, go

when I run `dep ensure`

/home/jenkins/workspace/myproject-voter is not within a known `GOPATH/src`

we have go installed on this docker image , I know that the project is not cloned to `go/src` but my question is if via `set env` or something I can do some trick to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> my question is if via set env or something I can do some trick to overcome this issue ?

Not "set env", but [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env):

```
ENV GOPATH=/path/to/your/Go/project
```

That would ensure any Go command is using the right workspace.

Comment: Shoud go project be `/usr/local/go` as its default installed folder?

Comment: @alper `go install` goes to `$GOPATH/bin`, which by default is `~/go/bin`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54429573/6309